# Get optgroup label in a Bootstrap Select

Tags: jquery, html

I have BootStrap select box and I am trying to find the optgroup of the selected option.

Here's a representation of a bootstrap select box with these options:

```
<li rel="1">
  <div class="div-contain">
     <div class="divider"></div>
  </div>
  <dt>
     <span class="text">Option Set 1</span> <!-- I NEED THIS: Option Set 1 -->
  </dt>
  <a tabindex="0" class="opt " style="">
    <span class="text">Option 1</span>
    <i class="fa fa-ok icon-ok check-mark"></i>
  </a>
</li>

<li rel="2" class="selected">
  <a tabindex="0" class="opt " style="">
    <span class="text">Option 2</span>
    <i class="fa fa-ok icon-ok check-mark"></i>
  </a>
</li>
```

**EDIT:**
My recent try based on @Soren Beck Jensen answer:

```
$('i.check-mark').closest('li.selected').find('dt>span').text();
```

This gives me 'Option Set 1' for all and any options I select in the first dropdown.

Comment: Also.... could you submit an example that shows the HTML with more than one option set and where one of the options are selected.

Comment: Sure, I will try and create a JS Fiddle. Also, see `<li rel="2">` which has selected as a class.

Comment: Yes but that is not inside option set 1? I think the structure is incorrect.

Comment: Your example does not make sense. It says rel="2" is selected but you want the result from option 1. Please clarify the question. Also take out the initial HTML block in your question as it is not relevant.

Comment: The optgroup labels are placed in <dt> tags in the first option of the option group in a bootstrap select.

Comment: I just realized that you are most likely writing all the HTML above. Why not just add whatever value you need to the options?

Answer (score 1):

Currently your example is wrong, but try this:

```
$('li.selected').find('dt').find('span').text();
```

Comment: What if there are 3 such select boxes on the page, all three of them will have check-mark icon tags

Comment: I need to know something unique about the selected option.

Comment: You can find it through the ID of the current select box?

Comment: No this gives me Option Set 1 for any selected options. Also, if I select any option under Option Set 1 then I get "Option Set1Option Set1" (twice)

Comment: Notice the problem for first option, if that is selected then the optgroup label is beneath it, not above it!

Comment: upvote for trying and helping me out, it was close enough but didn't work totally

Answer (score 0):

I don't necessarily know that you need to go to the trouble of navigating the rendered bootstrap dom elements to get what you need.  It seems much simpler to me to just access the original `<select>` markup.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    let picker = $('.selectpicker');
        picker.selectpicker();

    $(document).on('click', picker, function () {
        $('#group').html(
            $('option:selected', picker).parent('optgroup').prop('label') || 'no group'
        );
        $('#text').html(
            $('option:selected', picker).text()
        );
        $('#value').html(
            picker.val()
        );
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.9/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.9/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<select class="selectpicker">
    <optgroup label="A" >
        <option value="1">A - One</option>
        <option value="2">A - Two</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="B">
        <option value="3">B - Three</option>
        <option value="4">B - Four</option>
    </optgroup>
    <option value="nothing">No Group</option>
    <optgroup label="C">
        <option value="5">C - Five</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
<div>
  <div>
    Group: <span id="group"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    Value: <span id="value"></span>
  </div>
    <div>
    Text: <span id="text"></span>
  </div>
  <div id="text"></div>
</div>
```